# Visual Studio: How to have explicit type by default

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, var

We have Visual studio(2013) and resharper(V9), and currently by default, when create a new variable, we always have the first proposal as `var`. We are kind of allergic of this `var`(this is our opinion,I can accept that other doesn't have the same, but that's not the point). We can select with the keyboard arrows the explicit type, but we would like have it by default.

I'm not sure if that default comes from Resharper or from Visual Studio, but does anyone has an idea how to have the explicit implementation instead of the var?

Is this something we can do directly for the whole team?

Comment: did you check http://joel.fjorden.se/static.php?page=CodeStyleEnforcer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R# Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Code Style -> 'var' usage in declarations

[image]