# How to have "var" usage(instead of explicit type) considered as a warning?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, var, jetbrains-ide

By default, Resharper seems to encourage the usage of the var keyword(which I don't really understand, but it's not the point). For our project we deactivated this check, but we would like to have the opposite one: If someone use a var, to have a warning displayed.

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReSharper suggests the usage of var - Can it do the opposite thing aswell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630460/resharper-suggests-the-usage-of-var-can-it-do-the-opposite-thing-aswell)

Comment: `var` exists for a good reason; do you really enjoy writing things like `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyClassWithAVeryLongNameThatTakesAgesToType>>`? I don't... Also, it's the only way to use anonymous types.

Comment: And how would you use anonymous types then? Or they are also considered too dangerous in your project?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque This is not the question

Comment: @J4N and this is why I posted a comment, not an answer...

Comment: @Evk It's about having a warning when "Var is used INSTEAD of an explicit declaration", anonymous types cannot have explicit declaration, so no warnings ;)

Comment: @AshwinNair: I saw this question, but there is no answer that match his question.

Comment: @J4N, did you look at this answer in that question i posted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32630682/5159431 ? It says you can give a warning ('Notify with' column) if someone uses a declaration without an explicit type. So, if someone uses `var`, they'll get a warning (or hint or error if you prefer). This is what you (this question at least) seem to be asking for, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS 2015, ReSharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> Code style the following settings make it so that it generates a warning whenever you use var as a type.

[image]

Comment: Well, I still can't have a warning when a "var" is used instead of an explicit type. I already have the code style disabled for explicit -> var, but the opposite doesn't seems to exists.

Comment: Updated answer generates a warning for me, which I can easily fix by Ctrl + '.'

Comment: Now that I am looking around you have asked the same question previously ... at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604291/visual-studio-how-to-have-explicit-type-by-default?rq=1 . If you're looking for how to have the same settings propagated to an entire team of developpers you should look into solution wide Setting layers